# How to link to an EmbeddedDocument in MongoMapper?

Tags: mongodb, mongomapper

I'm not very confident about this schema design (suggestions welcome), but I have two collections:

- Business
- Customer

and each of them contains embedded documents:

- Businesses contain Events
- Customers contain Registrations

The class definitions are below, but first, the question.  When I create a Business and add an Event, everything looks fine.  When I create a Customer and add a Registration, everything looks fine.  At this point, I can do:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :380 > customer1.registrations.first.customer
 => #<Customer _id: BSON::ObjectId('4eb22a5bbae7a01331000019'), business_id: BSON::ObjectId('4eb215a9bae7a01331000001'), registrations: nil>
```

Perfect!  But then... I add the Registration to the Event using `event1.registrations << registration1`, and now `event1` has a different `customer` reference depending on whether I access it through the Event or through the Customer:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :444 > customer1.registrations.first.customer
 => #<Customer _id: BSON::ObjectId('4eb22a5bbae7a01331000019'), business_id: BSON::ObjectId('4eb215a9bae7a01331000001'), posts: nil> 

ruby-1.9.2-p180 :445 > business1.events.first.registrations.first.customer
 => #<Event _id: BSON::ObjectId('4eb21ab2bae7a0133100000f'), business_id: BSON::ObjectId('4eb215a9bae7a01331000001'), posts: nil> 

ruby-1.9.2-p180 :446 > business1.events.first.registrations.first == customer1.registrations.first
 => true
```

Not perfect.... my best guess is that duplicates of `registration1` have been embedded in both `customer1` and `event1`?  What I wanted was links between the Event and its many Registrations (which are owned and embedded in Customers).  Is that possible with this schema?

This is what my models look like.  They all have additional (and irrelevant) keys that are not displayed:

```
class Business
  include MongoMapper::Document

  many :events
  many :customers
end

class Event
  include MongoMapper::EmbeddedDocument

  embedded_in :business

  many :registrations
end

class Customer
  include MongoMapper::Document

  belongs_to :business
  key :business_id, ObjectId

  many :registrations
end

class Registration
  include MongoMapper::EmbeddedDocument

  embedded_in :customer

  belongs_to :event
  key :event_id, ObjectId
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep.  `Registration` is a `MongoMapper::EmbeddedDocument` so it's always embedded.  That means because both `Customer` and `Event` have `many :registrations`, different registration objects will be embedded in each.

In MongoMapper, the `embedded_in :customer` just alias a `customer` method to return the document's parent.  It's just a fancier way of calling `_parent_document`.  That's why your event's registration's customer is an event object.  ([See source here](https://github.com/jnunemaker/mongomapper/blob/master/lib/mongo_mapper/plugins/embedded_document.rb#L16)).

The [rule of thumb](http://mongomapper.com/frequent-questions/) is to only embed when the child will *always* be used in context of its parent.

Comment: Thank you!!  That helps a ton... Is there a way to link to the embedded document instead?  Potentially by indexing the embedded document ids, and then just storing an array of ObjectIds in the Event?